# Ac suppy provide to dc ammeter then what is the result

Tags: ac

Suppose if 220v and 50Hz voltage provide to DC ammeter then what will shows output?

Answer (score 4):

smoke.

You shall never attach an ammeter to a potential.

---

Edit:
You basically short circuit the potential because of the low inner resistance of the ammeter.

Answer (score 1):

Smoke is the correct answer, but I want to explain why that is:

An ammeter is built to measure the current in a circuit that includes a certain load (e.g. a light bulb). To minimize the measurement error the ammeter is built with a minimal resistance. Connecting it to an unloaded power source is basically creating a short circuit.

You have to take a step back and think about what you want to measure: my guess is that you don't want to know the maximum current when short circuiting your voltage source.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the smoke. It is correct except that the reason for the low resistance of the ammeter is not only the desire of minimal measurement error. In fact, the cheapest way to measure current is the indirect measurement of a voltage across a known impedance. To keep the dissipated power and voltage drop low, the resistance is mostly chosen to low value. While the dissipated power in the so called shunt resistor induces heat and therefore a measurement error (if not compensated), also the voltage drop is low and needs to be amplified, what also creates uncertainties.

Comment: @DPF: You raise an interesting point, except that analog voltmeters work by measuring the current through a known impedance. In fact, any kind of integrating ADC (like the kind found in most digital multimeters) do essentially the same thing. Analog ammeters work by using a shunt resistor selected such that a known fraction of the current passes through the meter itself. However, you are right about digital ammeters -- they generally convert the current to a voltage, which they then convert to a current that actually gets measured.